# what distribution should I use for this question?

Tags: probability

> The Canadian Mint produces dimes with an average diameter of 1 centimeter and standard deviation of 0.01
>
> a) Find an upper bound for the probability that a dime has a diameter of more than 2
>
>  b) Find a lower bound for the number of coins in a lot of 100 coins that are expected to have a diameter between 0.95 and 1.05
>
>  c) Let $\bar X_{72}$= $1 \over 72$ ($X_1+...X_{72}$) be the average diameter of 72 coins produced by this company. Then find $P(0.91\le \bar X_{72} \le 1.08)$

Should I use Markov and Chebyshev Inequalities for this question? And how to calculate c)? thanks for help!

Comment: For (c) the normal approximation should give reliable results. For bounds for individual coins, Chebyshev should do it, you know the variance.

Comment: The title does not reflect the content of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) By the Chebyshev Inequality, $\Pr(|X-\mu|\ge k\sigma)\le \frac{1}{k^2}$. Here $k\sigma=2-1$, and $\sigma=0.01$, so $k=100$.

(b) I am not sure what this is asking for. It sounds like a lower bound for an *expectation*. If $p$ is the probability that a coin is between the two given weights, then the expected number in a lot of $100$ is $100p$. By the Chebyshev Inequality, the probability of being wihin $5$ standard deviation units of the mean is $\gt 1-\frac{1}{5^2}$. Multiply by $100$.

Note that the bounds in (a) and (b) are undoubtedly absurdly pessimistic.

(c) The sample mean $\bar{X}_{72}$ has mean $1$ and standard deviation $\frac{0.01}{\sqrt{72}}$. It is reasonable to assume that $\bar{X}_{72}$ has a near to normal distribution. Note that in terms of standard deviation units for $\bar{X}_{72}$, the number $0.91$ is hugely below $1$, and $1.08$ is hugely above $1$. So the required probability is nearly $1$.

We **could** use Chebyshev Inequality estimates, changing the $0.91$ to $0.92$. We would conclude that the probability is greater than $1-\frac{1}{(72)(64)}$.

Comment: for part c, i don't quite get $0.1\over \sqrt72$

Comment: Thanks for spotting the typo. It should be $0.01$, the original standard deviation, divided by $\sqrt{72}$. Let $X_1,\dots,X_{72}$ be the sizes of our coins, assumed independent. Then the variance of the sum is the sum of the variances, so $(72)(0,01)^2$. When we divide by $72$ to get the sample mean, the variance gets divided by $72^2$. Now take the square root.